# Url Forwarding for invalid routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I'm upgrading an old asp.net webforms site. I want to make the URLs look nicer, so I'm using the routing system, like this:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("account settings",
        "settings/account/",
        "~/accountsettings.aspx");
}
```

This works fine. Urls like `mydomain.com/settings/account/` look much nicer. However, the page can still be accessed using its physical location, as `mydomain.com/accountsettings.aspx`. I'd like to forward requests to these old form urls to my new urls.

What's the best way to do this? Is there a simple method I can use, as with `RegisterRoutes`?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a specific method, but in `Page_Init` on each page, you can use `Response.RedirectToRoute()` to redirect to the correct route if the url includes an aspx extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll need to let the routing engine know to ignore the route of the physical file using IgnoreRoute:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("accountsettings.aspx");
```

Please double-check the syntax for IgnoreRoute as I don't remember if you'll need to include the relative path or just the file name.

Once you have that working you can trap the 404 that it will generate, possibly in the global error handler in global.asax, and redirect if that was the requested path.  This blog posting has an example of how to trap a 404 in the global error handler:  http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Handling-404-errors-with-ASPNET.aspx

If this is a public site and you're concerned about SEO you may also want to consider specifying that it's a permanent redirect using http status code 301.  This will tell Google and other search engines that the old page now exists at the new location and you won't lose the value from that page.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This method sounds good. I'm not so sure about ignoring the route in one place, then handling 404s somewhere else though. I'll see if I can work out a way to do them all at once.